# ETH sent to contract address, how to get it back?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

Instead of transferring my ETH token to my wallet, I accidentally sent it to some contract address, this one: 0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564.
Is there any way to get my ETH back?

Comment: Link to transaction?

Comment: this contract has no ether, add tx hash